# ASP.NET "Resource not found" when attempting to execute an ActionResult method in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add an Edit functionality to my MVC5 application, but whenever I try to call my `Edit` method in the `Search` view, I get an error saying that the resource `localhost:xxxx/Search/EditClient` doesn't exist.

`EditClient` is just a method in my controller, and I have to return a `RedirectToAction`.

Here's my controller:

```cs
public class SearchController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult SearchClient() {
        //Just returning the default view for the search page
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SearchClient(string SearchId)
    {
        //I do have validations in case the ID doesn't exist, but I'm omitting them from this question to avoid inflating the code.
        Client clientFound = (Client)Session[SearchId];
        //SearchId is the ID attribute for my Client object. If the ID was in the Session variable, it will retrieve the corresponding object and I'll use it for the model in my view.
        return View("SearchClient", clientFound);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditClient(Client client)
    {
        Session[client.Id] = client;
        return RedirectToAction("SearchClient");
    }
}
```

My View

```
@model MVCExample.Models.Client

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    ViewBag.Message = "Look for Clients";
}

<h1 class="store-title">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<h2 class="page-title">@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchClient", "Search"))
{
   <p>Search for User ID: @Html.TextBox("SearchId")</p></br>
   <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName), new { @class = "control-label" }
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" }

   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("EditClient, "Search", FormMethod.Post)">Save Changes</a>
}
```

I can successfully retrieve a user and have their data displayed, but whenever I try to change it (In this example I only created a field for FullName, but I have fields for every property) and save the changes, I get redirected to an error page saying that Search/EditClient doesn't exist.
I thought that redirecting to an action would fix that, so why does it seem like my app is trying to display the wrong view?

Comment: Aren't you missing `[HttpPost]` attribute?

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa I forgot to write it on the post, but it is part of the code. I already added it. It's still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ancor tag always generates a Get method. It doesn't submit a form, it just calls a GET action with provided parameters. If you want to POST a form it is better to use a button. And you need to call EditClient action. Try this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditClient", "Search",  FormMethod.Post))
    {
..... your code
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes"/>
    }
```

I can't see your startup file so maybe you can try to use routing

```
    [Route("~/Search/EditClient")]
    public ActionResult EditClient(Client client)
    {
 .....
     }
```

Comment: But I'm already using a method in the `@using` Form control. SearchClient populates the Form fields in the view whereas EditClient saves changes done on those fields, I need to trigger those 2 methods. Wouldn't adding that just not allow me to use SearchClient?

Comment: @Dasph There are dozens way to submit the form. I explained in my answer why your code is not working and offer you the one of algorighms that is usually working. Did you try it? Do you have any errors now?

Comment: I did try it and it's unfortunately not working, having the same issue.

Comment: Thank you, there was a typo in a route along with the issues you mentioned, now it's properly redirecting to the right page.

Answer (score 1):

If it's required to have the `Search` and `Edit` functionality you can use two `Html.BeginForm()`:

```
@model MVCExample.Models.Client
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    ViewBag.Message = "Look for Clients";
}

<h1 class="store-title">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<h2 class="page-title">@ViewBag.Message</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchClient", "Search"))
{
    <div>
        <p>Search for User ID: @Html.TextBox("SearchId")</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.FullName)
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditClient", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.FullName)
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
}
```

Apply the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the `EditClient` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditClient(Client client)
{
    Session[client.Id] = client;
    return RedirectToAction("SearchClient");
}
```

Unfortunately impossibly to use `href="@Url.Action()` to send the `Post` in this context. If you want to create `href` you need to start dealing with the `@Ajax.ActionLink()`.

Comment: I forgot to type it but it's actually there, error still happens

Comment: I tried the code in the edit and it's unfortunately not working. Same issue, it is attempting to retrieve a view called EditClient rather than actually returning to the standard Search View

Comment: @Dasph: Add the model definition `Client`  to your post, please.

Comment: It was an issue with the routes (along with what you mentioned). Already managed to get it working, now there's only an issue with the changes not actually being saved, but that's an issue for a different queston. Thank you.